# MS SQL service Broker multiple readers start not instantly

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, service-broker

I have a MS SQL service Broker setup and running.
TestQueue has attached stored procedure `[TestProc]` and set `MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 3`.
TestProc has a `WAIT_FOR DELAY '00:00:05'` to simulate work.

Now I'm sending 6 messages to queue.
First runner starts instantly, but only 1! After the first completes, 2 more are starting, and only after these 2 complete, 3 more start.

How can I force Broker to start all 3 threads instantly, without waiting anything?

Comment: [Understanding Activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms171601%28v%3dsql.105%29): "... a simpler approach, such as the number of unread messages in the queue, might waste resources."

Comment: this is clear, but this doesnt solve the problem. i want messages to be processed as fast as possible, i dont want to wait before sp finishes. what if it will finish in 1 minute? but others could finish within a millisecond. but they will not fire because the first is still running (not on the same dialog, so its ok to process it by other reader).
in my real life app requests will come in a batch, so i want to start 5 SPs simultaneously, not 1-2-3-4-5-5-5-5 SPs.

Comment: That may be what you want, but it doesn't match how the activation system for service broker has been built. And it's not waiting for the first one to finish, per se, it's just that after launching a new instance, it waits a few seconds to see whether all of the now running instances are able to keep up with the demand.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use an expernal app (a Windows service) that issues as many pending `WAITFOR (RECEIVE ... )` concurrent statements as you wish.

The built-in Activation mechanism is built to ramp up slowly and you cannot change this.